# Different where clause columns based on group by count of joined table

Tags: mysql, join, count, group-by

Given the following 2 tables

```
table_a
id    name      num_one      num_two
------------------------------------
1     Foo       5            10
2     Bar       4            -1


table_b
name      table_a_id
--------------------
Fooa      1
Foob      1
```

Suppose I want to use ether num_one or num_two in a where clause depending on if another table has joined rows or not.

The best thing I can come up with is this:

```
SELECT a.* FROM table_a a
JOIN table_b b on b.table_a_id = a.id
WHERE if(count(b.*) > 0, a.num_one, a.num_two) > 0
group by a.id
```

Ideally it would check if 5 > 0 on the first row and -1 > 0 on the 2nd because the 2nd row as no joined rows from table B.

But it errors with invalid use of group by. I know about "having" but not sure how I could use it in this situation.

Any ideas? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with an IF statement, OR statement or a subquery. None of which will be very efficient on a large table.

The only real modification to your original statement was the use of `NULL` instead of count(*).

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.* 
FROM table_a a
LEFT JOIN table_b b on b.table_a_id = a.id
WHERE (b.table_a_id is null AND a.num_one > 0) 
   OR (b.table_a_id is NOT NULL AND a.num_two > 0)
```

Comment: Note: if you know that `table_b` only contains one record for each corresponding record in `table_a`, the `DISTINCT` clause is not necessary.